# Angular2 TypeScript Bundle Issue - components no loaded/initialized

Tags: angular

I am able to concatenate all of the typescript files into one bundle by specifying outFile:"/app/mybundle.js" attribute in tsconfig.json.

Before creating this bundle I was using the below Systemjs code to import my angular components and initialize app which was fine.

```
<script>
        System.config({
            packages: { 'app': { defaultExtension: 'js' } },
        });
        System.import('app/myappp')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

But when I create this bundle and update my Systemjs code to the following:

```
<script>
        System.config({
            packages: { 'app': { defaultExtension: 'js' } },
        });
        System.import('/app/mybundle')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

All I see on my screen is just Loading, the components aren't loaded/initialized. Although I don't see any error in log or 404 for bundle file.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when using the `outFile` attribute, the modules aren't anonymous modules anymore. They are registered by names so you don't need to configure SystemJS to map module names with corresponding files, i.e. what you do with the `packages` block.

Without the `outFile` attribute, in module files:

```
System.register([ 'dep', ..., function...
```

With the `outFile` attribute, in module files:

```
System.register('modulename', [ 'dep', ..., function...
```

There is a first string parameter added corresponding to the name of the module in the second case.

Just do this:

```
<script>
    System.import('mybundle')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Note that the `app` level doesn't exist anymore in the module names.

Comment: Still no success, unless I add System.import('mybundle.js'), I see 404 in log. And when I add .js extension the 404 error is gone but the component isn't still loaded. I have <mycomponent>Loading...</mycomponent> in index file

Comment: In fact, you simply need to add the `mybundle.js` file into a `script` element and import the main module by its name. In your case: `System.import('myappp')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));`. This import could be added at the end of the body...

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I added the script file and after that I added System.import('myappp') .then(null, console.error.bind(console)); but when I refresh it in browser its looking for the file with name myappp in root directory, I am not sure why?

Comment: SystemJS looks for a file for a module when it can't find it from its name first. SO in your case, the `myappp` module can't be found... Do you have a line like this in your `bundle.js` file: ` System.register('myappp', ...`?

Comment: If so, perhaps you import your module too early. Try to move the import at the end of the `body` tag of your HTML page...

Comment: I have grouped components in different folders, so my typescripts files are in scripts/usserrole/feature. So I had to add the path to System.import i.e.

System.import('components/userrole/mycomponent.component').then(null, console.error.bind(console));

This removed the 404 error, but still not showing any contents on the page.